# Как достать словарь из JSON (https://api.coinmarketcap.com)

Tags: python, json

Имеется `json` объект который выводит вот такого рода лист
`[{}]`

```
r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
    price = json.loads(r.text)

    print(price)
```

Как я могу вытащить из него определенный словарь?

Comment: а что вы хотите "вытащить"?

Comment: По индексам, `print(price[0])` получим первый словарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [12]: [x for x in r.json() if x['symbol'] == 'PART']
Out[12]:
[{'24h_volume_usd': '507118.0',
  'available_supply': '7794023.0',
  'id': 'particl',
  'last_updated': '1512411573',
  'market_cap_usd': '72737020.0',
  'max_supply': None,
  'name': 'Particl',
  'percent_change_1h': '0.18',
  'percent_change_24h': '1.61',
  'percent_change_7d': '-4.19',
  'price_btc': '0.00083332',
  'price_usd': '9.33241',
  'rank': '100',
  'symbol': 'PART',
  'total_supply': '8790023.0'}]
```

Также можно воспользоваться Pandas:

```
In [14]: import pandas as pd

In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   24h_volume_usd available_supply            id last_updated market_cap_usd     max_supply          name percent_change_1h  \
0    6846280000.0       16719862.0       bitcoin   1512411554   188723770339     21000000.0       Bitcoin             -1.16
1    1076090000.0       96132524.0      ethereum   1512411563  44158571118.0           None      Ethereum             -1.07
2     860631000.0       16837813.0  bitcoin-cash   1512411577  25638768716.0     21000000.0  Bitcoin Cash              -1.2
3     119715000.0    38622870411.0        ripple   1512411541   9626286975.0   100000000000        Ripple             -0.34
4    1035820000.0     2779530283.0          iota   1512411570   8107584087.0   2779530283.0          IOTA               2.1
5     162263000.0        7733246.0          dash   1512411543   5862859625.0     18900000.0          Dash              -0.7
6     147105000.0       16688174.0  bitcoin-gold   1512411580   5342952409.0     21000000.0  Bitcoin Gold             -0.33
7     349641000.0       54125358.0      litecoin   1512411541   5322049042.0     84000000.0      Litecoin             -0.27
8      70234400.0    25927070538.0       cardano   1512411579   3424395623.0  45000000000.0       Cardano             -0.34
9      76397500.0       15433120.0        monero   1512411546   3112458968.0           None        Monero              0.81
..            ...              ...           ...          ...            ...            ...           ...               ...
90      2766100.0       24488904.0      peercoin   1512411541     84326315.0           None      Peercoin             -1.83
91      7314160.0      286170756.0      loopring   1512411576     83087676.0           None      Loopring             -1.47
92      2812980.0        2455648.0       zencash   1512411569     81729611.0     21000000.0       ZenCash              1.91
93      6418390.0       62120072.0      nav-coin   1512411546     81404006.0           None      NAV Coin              -2.0
94     11724100.0       60248315.0       adx-net   1512411575     80751419.0    100000000.0          AdEx             -0.07
95      1691620.0       39138253.0          ubiq   1512411548     79203691.0           None          Ubiq             -0.12
96      6608050.0      350000000.0     chainlink   1512411578     78556800.0           None     ChainLink             -0.23
97     15927800.0      617314171.0    quantstamp   1512411584     77022906.0           None    Quantstamp             -1.83
98      5010750.0     1007995646.0        bitbay   1512411553     73715226.0           None        BitBay             -3.01
99       507118.0        7794023.0       particl   1512411573     72737020.0           None       Particl              0.18

   percent_change_24h percent_change_7d   price_btc  price_usd rank symbol   total_supply
0               -4.03             16.53         1.0    11287.4    1    BTC     16719862.0
1               -4.36             -4.09    0.041017    459.351    2    ETH     96132524.0
2                -6.3             -7.58    0.135966    1522.69    3    BCH     16837813.0
3               -3.96             -1.19  0.00002226   0.249238    4    XRP  99993173757.0
4               50.32            196.48  0.00026046    2.91689    5  MIOTA   2779530283.0
5               -3.64             20.17   0.0676966    758.137    6   DASH      7733246.0
6               -3.96            -11.63   0.0285885    320.164    7    BTG     16788174.0
7               -5.25              8.78  0.00878006    98.3282    8    LTC     54125358.0
8               -2.25            172.26  0.00001179   0.132078    9    ADA  31112483745.0
9               -1.59             20.99   0.0180082    201.674   10    XMR     15433120.0
..                ...               ...         ...        ...  ...    ...            ...
90              -4.69             72.46  0.00030748    3.44345   91    PPC     24488904.0
91              -0.69             40.57  0.00002593   0.290343   92    LRC   1395076054.0
92               5.21              4.88  0.00297189    33.2823   93    ZEN      2455648.0
93              12.36              11.7  0.00011701    1.31043   94    NAV     62120072.0
94               0.95              7.53  0.00011968    1.34031   95    ADX    100000000.0
95               5.23             30.21   0.0001807    2.02369   96    UBQ     39138253.0
96             -10.71             24.59  0.00002004   0.224448   97   LINK   1000000000.0
97              -8.56            -20.07  0.00001114   0.124771   98    QSP    976442388.0
98               8.33             -5.36  0.00000653  0.0731305   99    BAY   1007995646.0
99               1.61             -4.19  0.00083332    9.33241  100   PART      8790023.0

[100 rows x 15 columns]

In [17]: df.loc[df['name'].isin(['Bitcoin','Ethereum','Bitcoin Cash'])]
Out[17]:
  24h_volume_usd available_supply            id last_updated market_cap_usd  max_supply          name percent_change_1h  \
0   6846280000.0       16719862.0       bitcoin   1512411554   188723770339  21000000.0       Bitcoin             -1.16
1   1076090000.0       96132524.0      ethereum   1512411563  44158571118.0        None      Ethereum             -1.07
2    860631000.0       16837813.0  bitcoin-cash   1512411577  25638768716.0  21000000.0  Bitcoin Cash              -1.2

  percent_change_24h percent_change_7d price_btc price_usd rank symbol total_supply
0              -4.03             16.53       1.0   11287.4    1    BTC   16719862.0
1              -4.36             -4.09  0.041017   459.351    2    ETH   96132524.0
2               -6.3             -7.58  0.135966   1522.69    3    BCH   16837813.0
```